# Is there a way to find exact location ( adress ) of file on disk?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, memory, disk

I'm developing a software using C++ for Windows/Linux.

I want to create a file (txt, json, license, you name it) at runtime, and save it somewhere. Is it possible in C++ to get the exact position of that file on disk, so that if I restart the app and read that address (or other), I'll be able to access its data?

The purpose of this would be that if someone copied the software to another OS, or created an image of the OS, and tried to run it, the address would not be valid anymore and it would fail. This is an attempt to add another layer (on top of license management) to protect against software copy.

Comment: Does this question assume that the location of a file on disk would never change?  And if run on a different computer, it _would_ change?

Comment: A disk defragmentation utility running in the background would break this protection very quickly.

Comment: FWIW, I protect my software using a licensing server, keyed on the users email address (which he / she must supply when they purchase).  Also included in the license key is the customer's full name, so that if they do share the key they are at least 'named and shamed'.  Doing these two things seems to be enough to protect me from any significant piracy.

Comment: Anyone wanting to pirate your software will just download the fix from the internet that negates that check. All you are going to achieve is to annoy your actually paying customers when your check fails and claims properly paid for instances of the software were stolen.

Comment: You don't want to completely rule out copying / additional installs though. What if someone gets a new machine? (Such at because they're upgrading from they old one or it straight up died.) Presumably you don't want to force them to re-purchase your software. I suggest to start researching existing registration / activation schemes for software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An image of a disk copies it byte by byte, meaning that all addresses (locations) on disk stay exactly the same. So your copy protection won't actually work - you can still easily clone the disk while preserving your special copy protection file. Additionally, a file may not even have a defined location on disk: It may be split up into many fragments and scattered across the entire disk. You can't find an address that doesn't exist. The filesystem may also just move the file around whenever it feels like it so the address doesn't stay the same even on the same system. (This is what defragmentation does. Windows, for example, moves files around like that on a fixed schedule to make the filesystem faster.)

TL;DR this is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for your instructive and quick answer !